# debug an evaluate expression on intellij

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, intellij-idea

Using evaluate expression/code fragment:

https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/evaluating-expressions.html

Is it possible to debug evaluated expression/code fragment on intellij?.

On eclipse if you launch a code evaluation on display window and that code has any breakpoint inside, eclipse debugger stops on that breakpoint. If you try again eclipse says it can execute inspections on nested debug session.

Intellij seems to launch expression in a different session.

My workflow on this is to stop on "whatever line" of code and add fragment I want to evaluate for a Q&D debug. Many times this leads to a debug restart.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is not possible, but I don't have any official source...

Comment: I'm also awaiting this for YEARS now. Would be an incedible powerful feature!

Comment: Select the variable that you want to evaluate and press `Alt + F8`. Detail steps is given here: https://www.websparrow.org/misc/shortcut-key-to-evaluate-expression-variable-in-intellij-idea

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Unfortunately it's not possible in Intellij 14 and stated in the official link you provided:

> If a method invoked within the **Expression Evaluation** has a breakpoint inside its body, this breakpoint will be ignored.

To eliminate the problem you mentioned with frequent restarting of a debug session I use the following work-around with the drop-frame debug feature:

1. Step in to a method and before return use the drop-frame functionality to fall back to a previous stack frame. See the drop-frame icon's location on the screenshot below:
   [image]
2. Now it's possible to rerun this method with different parameters without restarting the debug session (parameters can be set using Evaluate Expression dialog).

Comment: This won't help with EL expressions

Comment: Thank you so much for this! I've been looking for a way to debug like this for ages

Comment: This is magic bro, thank you for sharing, I feel this will save me hours of work!

Answer (score 1):

The feature is not available in IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2

The workaround I use is to update the code as follows,

```
                    Boolean shouldExecute = false;
                    if(shouldExecute){
                        //method call
                    }
```

During the debug session, I will change *shouldExecute* flag to true. This way I can debug the *method call* when needed.

Of coarse this is just a workaround, I need to remove this flag later.

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F8</kbd> is the shortcut for evaluation of an expression or variable.

However, you can also select the variable, right click on it and evaluate as explained in [this article](https://www.websparrow.org/misc/shortcut-key-to-evaluate-expression-variable-in-intellij-idea).